# Converting an HtmlElement into an Image?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image, webbrowser-control

I'm using a WebBrowser control in VB.Net to load a website.  At that point, the WebBrowser.Document.Images property returns a collection of HtmlElement that are considered images.

What I'm trying to do at this point, is take a particular HtmlElement that represents an image and turn it into a System.Drawing.Image so that I can manipulate it.  But I can't figure out how.

I did try to search for an answer, but came up with nothing.  'WebBrowser', as it turns out, seems to be a really popular keyword.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:  It's been suggested that I use the SRC attribute of the HtmlElement to download the image; but the image can be dynamic - meaning the image I download can be separate from the image on the website....so, that won't work for my purposes.

Comment: Try putting the image element into clipboard. i.e. Clipboard.SetData(browser1.document.images(1)). Does that work at all?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked with the WebBrowser object, but from the image you should be able to get the src-attribute somehow, and using that, you could do a request to that:

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
wr.Method = "GET";
```

and then you should be able to treat the response stream as an image:

```
Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
img.Save(...);
```

Comment: +1 HttpWebRequest. I did not realize it had a `GetResponseStream` method.

Comment: This is a good answer; but unless I'm misunderstanding, it doesn't really work for my situation.  When I load the website in the WebControl the image generated and shown in the web-browser is the one I need.  If I use the src-attribute and make a second request, the image returned will not be the same image as the one in the WebBrowser.

Answer (score 1):

Well, next time, try *IWebBrowser* as the keyword. That should lead you to the MSDN documentation.

I am not positive but I do not think what you want can be done directly. However, you could use the `src` property through the [IHTMLImgElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752250(VS.85).aspx) to download the image to `%TEMP%` and initialize a `System.Drawing.Image` object using the [`FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx) method